# Printing from within an object

Tags: python, methods, printing

I have tried to get one python object to inherit another. I wrote a script to test things were working (see below). However, when I try to access the methods within those objects nothing gets printed and I cant understand why. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
print("hello world")

class parent():
    def helloWorld(self, ):
        print("hello World1")

class child(parent):
    def helloWorld2(self, ):
        print("hello World2")

parentOBJ = parent()
childOBJ = child()


parentOBJ.helloWorld
childOBJ.helloWorld
childOBJ.helloWorld2
```

The code above prints the first "hello world" statement but nothing after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not calling the methods. Add `()` after each method when you want to call them. Otherwise your interpreter will only return the type of the object.

```
parentOBJ.helloWorld()
childOBJ.helloWorld()
childOBJ.helloWorld2()
```

However you'll have to fix your class definitions as well:

```
class parent(object): # All classes should inherit from the object-class
    def helloWorld(self): # unless you have other arguments besides self, remove the comma.
        print("hello World1")

class child(parent):
    def helloWorld2(self):
        print("hello World2")
```

Example:

```
>>> parentOBJ = parent()
>>> childOBJ = child()
>>> parentOBJ.helloWorld()
hello World1
>>> childOBJ.helloWorld()
hello World1
>>> childOBJ.helloWorld2()
hello World2
```

Answer (score 3):

You are simply referencing the methods and not **actually** making a call to them.

Do this instead:

```
parentOBJ.helloWorld()
childOBJ.helloWorld()
childOBJ.helloWorld2()
```

When you make a call to a function, you have to do `method_name(arguments)`.

So if I have a method called `def hello(a, b):`, I will actually need to pass the arguments to the function as well, something as follows: `hello('hello', 'world')`.

#### Example

```
>>> def hello(): 
...     print 'hello' 
...  
>>> hello
<function hello at 0x2340bc>
>>> hello()
hello
```

Hope that helps.